# GetElementById using variable is giving hard time

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a variable to check what form ID has invoked the `onClick` event. I tried to go through everything on stack but I am still not sure why `getElementById` is returning `null`. Here is what my code looks like -

```
<form id="mul_f" name="mulf" method="post">
    <select id= "mul" name="libraries">                    
        <?php include (__DIR__ ."/include/syshost.php"); ?>
    </select>
    From Date:<input id="mul_fd" name="mulfd" type="date">
    <button id="mulb" type="button" value="submit" onclick="display(this.form.id)"> Submit </button>
    <div id="mul_chart_div"></div>    
    <div id="mul_table_div"></div>
</form>
```

my function -

```
function display(s) {
    var x = document.getElementById(s); // returns null 
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { // errors out on x.length
        document.write(x.elements[i].value + "<br>");
    }
    document.write(s.id);   
    document.write(x.length);
}
```

Comment: if I hardcode the id to "mul_f" this works fine.

Comment: Why not just pass `this.form` ?

Comment: debug through to see the value of `s` that's making it return null.

Comment: It works fine in a fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5godo8j7/

Comment: I found that it is working fine with your code as well and @adeneo fiddle example

Answer (score 1):

I tried this -

```
<form id="mul_f" name="mulf" method="post">

                        <select id= "mul" name="libraries">
                        <?php include (__DIR__ ."/include/syshost.php"); ?>
                        </select>
                        From Date:<input id="mul_fd" name="mulfd" type="date">
                        <button id="mulb" type="button" value="submit" onclick="display(this.form)">Submit</button>
                        <div id="mul_chart_div"></div>
                        <div id="mul_table_div"></div>
```

function -

```
function display(s){
                document.write(s.id);
                //var x = document.getElementById(s.id);
                var x = s;
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                         document.write(x.elements[i].value + "<br>");
                }
                document.write(s.id);   
                        document.write(x.length);
        }
```

this works now. Thanks Max, Adeneo Travis.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function onButtonClick() {
    var form = getForm(this);
    if (form)
        alert(form.id);
}

function getForm(el) {
    if (el == el.parentNode || !el.parentNode)
        return null;
    if (el.parentNode.tagName == "FORM")
        return el.parentNode;
    else
        return getForm(el.parentNode);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
    }
})
```

```html
<form id="form1">
    <button type="button">In form 'form1'</button>
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <button type="button">In form 'form2'</button>
</form>
<!--Button out of from-->
<button type="button"> Out of from </button>
```

Answer (score -3):

`this` refers to the button element.

```
onclick="display(document.forms[0].id)">
```

Comment: And `this.form` would be the parent form